# How do I access my Windows Desktop directory from inside Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Ubuntu for my terminal. I am unable to access my Desktop and when I type "ls" nothing shows up. How do I log in via desktop environment in order to access my desktop files?

```
huque@RNB:~$ pwd
/home/huque
huque@RNB:~$ cd Desktop
-bash: cd: Desktop: No such file or directory
huque@RNB:~$ ls
huque@RNB:~$
```

**---EDIT 1----**
In response to @WinEunuuchs2Unix's comment, this is what happens when I type apt list ubuntu-desktop:

```
    huque@RNB:~$ apt list ubuntu-desktop
    Listing... Done
    ubuntu-desktop/bionic-updates 1.417.1 amd64
    N: There is 1 additional version. Please use the '-a' switch to see it
    huque@RNB:~$ -a
    -a: command not found
    huque@RNB:~$
```

**---EDIT 2----**
In response to @l0b0's comment, here is a screenshot of my terminal and the desktop image behind it.
[image: desktop]

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu Desktop? What does `apt list ubuntu-desktop` return?

Comment: I'm really sorry, but there is no `Desktop/` directory there! :/

Comment: Please show the output of this command: `ls -la`

Comment: Just as a side note, the `-a` is a "switch" or "flag" which means should be part of the command you already ran, so `apt list -a ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the desktop? I know we're asking a lot, but this situation shouldn't be possible.

Comment: screenshot has been added

Comment: First, there's no "Desktop" folder on your desktop. Second, that's Windows, not Linux/Unix.

Comment: Windows 10 comes with a linux subsystem which I have

Comment: @l0b0 [WSL is on topic](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5125/22222).

Comment: @AlyssaHuque please post the output of running `find / -type d -name Users` from the Ubuntu terminal. Also, please [edit] your question and explain what exactly you need to do. You cannot "log in via desktop environment" so we will need to find another way for you to do what you want. Do you just want to find the files on your Windows Desktop from within the Ubuntu command line?

Comment: You should reframe this question as "How do I access my Windows Desktop directory from inside Windows Subsystem for Linux?"  You aren't running a Linux desktop.  You're running a linux shell inside a windows subsystem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you're actually looking for is `/mnt/c/Users/huque/Desktop`. You can

```
ls /mnt/c/Users/huque/Desktop
```

to see what's in it, or

```
cd /mnt/c/Users/huque/Desktop
```

to actually be there. `/mnt/c` maps in your C: drive from Windows and you can access all your files through there.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Additionally, note that while you can access Windows files from Linux (WSL) in this way, you shouldn't write or edit Linux files using Windows tools as this will likely corrupt them.

Comment: @dr01 If you are up to date, you can freely open and edit whatever files you like (start with `explorer.exe .` and go nuts), though line endings may still occasionally be a problem. It installs a 9p server and client.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I haven't been using WSL for a while. Relevant blog post: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/

Comment: Is there a command to cd directly to `/mnt/c/Users/$USER` or do I have to create an alias myself for that?

Answer (score 2):

This simply means that there is no directory called "Desktop" in your home directory - nothing more or less. And /home/huque is not necessarily the same as c:\Users\huque.

Comment: I can see my Desktop and the files on my Desktop though through my normal computer interface. Why can I not see it through my terminal window?

Comment: Looking at the screenshot, which seems to list the contents of the home directory of *huque* the most obvious thing which comes to mind is you are looking into the wrong user's home directory, or looking at the wrong computer.

Comment: when I use powershell I can access Desktop (c:\Users\huque\Desktop) but I'm trying to avoid powershell since it doesn't have bash.

Comment: @AlyssaHuque the Desktop you see is your Windows Desktop, this has nothing to do with the Ubuntu Desktop. You don't have an Ubuntu Desktop and as far as I know, you can't have one within Windows. The Linux Subsystem you are using on Windows is a command line tool, it doesn't have any graphical interface.